# Using friend to reduce verbosity

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, friend

Is it considered a good practice to use `friend` to define global functions within the class definition, even when the access to private members is not needed. For example

```
template<typename T>
class A {
public:
    A(T v);
    T value() const;

    friend A operator+(T n, const A& a) {
        return A(a.value() + n);
    }
};
```

instead of

```
template<typename T>
class A {
public:
    A(T v);
    T value() const;
};

template<typename T>
A<T> operator+(T n, const A<T>& a) {
    return A<T>(a.value() + n);
}
```

even though `operator+` only uses `value()` which is public.
Is this commonly done, us is it not recommended?

Comment: Why do you want to break whole in your encapsulation? If you do not need encapsulation, just make all your members public. If you want encapsulation, do not friend left and right.

Comment: It's not recommended.

Comment: One advantage of the friend function is that it is not template, and some that change overload order resolution in some case.

Comment: @SergeyA Where does the definition of a `friend` function inlined in the class break _the rule of encapsulation_?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, why would you friend a function which doesn't need to access the private member?

Comment: @SergeyA Sure, you're right. I didn't spot that aspect.

Comment: "even when the access to private members is not needed" -> this is the only feature of friends class. it's basically like saying "what do you think about creating a function when no action is taken?"

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ if you omit the friend you are not allowed to define an `operator+` inside your class definition taking two arguments and therefore only able to define `A+T` but not `T+A` - i liked your (deleted) answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's one major advantage to `friend` here. When we define:

```
friend A operator+(T, const A&);
```

This is *not* a function template. This is just a function - a special one that can only be found by ADL. But since it's not a function template, conversions still can happen. On the flip side:

```
template <class T>
A<T> operator+(T, const A<T>&)
```

is a normal old function template with all of the normal rules regarding template type deduction.

Why does this matter? Consider:

```
A<double> a(4.2);
5 + a;
```

In the first case, this is perfectly fine. We find `operator+(double, const A<double>&)`, the `5` gets converted to `5.0`, which is an allowed conversion, and we get back `A<double>(9.2)`.

In the second case, template deduction fails because the `T` deduces to different types for the two arguments. Hence, the code is ill-formed.

Comment: You could mimic this behavior without resorting to `friend` with `std::is_convertible<X, T>` assuming the template was changed to `template <class X, class T>`, right?

Comment: @KurtStutsman Yeah, but template function + SFINAE is quite a bit more complicated than just a simple function...

Comment: I guess using `friend` is ok when the function is not a member, but is semantically part of the class. Because member functions also do not always need to have private access to the class.